# use ExecutorService.submit result get Garbled

Tags: java

I use [jPowerShell](https://github.com/profesorfalken/jPowerShell) to execute powershell in Java, but I got the garbled when I `executeCommand()`

Here is my code:

```
PowerShellResponse response = powerShell.executeCommand(getAll);
//Print results
System.out.println("result :" + response.getCommandOutput());
```

in `executeCommand()` use:

```
Future<String> result = threadpool.submit(commandProcessor);
commandOutput = result.get();
```

I do not know the how to encode the result.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help?

```
Future<String> result = threadpool.submit(commandProcessor);
while (!result.isDone()) {}
String commandOutput = result.get();
```